# Mocked repository returning object with null properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Here's a sample of one of my unit test classes (pared down to the basics). In the controller, when the Index() action method is invoked, a call to GetByID(1234) always results in a newed up instance of a Ticket object. The object exists, but all of its properties are null, even though I've set them in my fake object. Any ideas as to why?

I'm using Moq.

**Unit test**

```
    [TestClass]
    public class TicketControllerTests : ControllerTestBase
    {
        protected Mock<ITicketRepository> MockTicketRepository = new Mock<ITicketRepository>();

        [TestMethod]
        public void IndexActionModelIsTypeOfTicketModel()
        {
            //ARRANGE
            Mock<HttpContextBase> context = FakeHttpContext();
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session[SessionKeys.TokenData.ToString()]).Returns(Constants.TOKENDATA_SUBMITTER);

            MockTicketRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Constants.CLIENT_TICKET);

            //ACT
            var result = GetController(context.Object).Index(Constants.TICKET_ID);
            var model = ((ViewResult)result).Model;

            //ASSERT
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(model, typeof(TicketModel), "ViewModel should have been an instance of TicketModel.");
        }

        private TicketController GetController(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            var controller = new TicketController(MockTicketRepository.Object);
            controller.ControllerContext = GetControllerContext(context, controller);
            return controller;
        }
    }
```

**Constants.CLIENT_TICKET**

```
public static Ticket CLIENT_TICKET
        {
            get
            {
                var ticket = new Ticket
                {
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    CreatedByUserId = 4
                };

                ticket.Clients.Add(new Client { ShortName = "Test Client 1"});
                ticket.Clients.Add(new Client { ShortName = "Test Client 2" });

                ticket.User = new User {FirstName = "First", LastName = "Last"};

                return ticket;
            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
private readonly ITicketRepository _ticketRepository;

public TicketController(ITicketRepository ticketRepository)
{
    _ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
}

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var ticket = _ticketRepository.GetById(id);

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show the controller code under test? It could be related to how you have set up the mocked context but it's hard to tell without seeing the controller code.

Also, if you add `MockBehavior.Strict` when you create the mock, it will bomb out if the invocation doesn't have a corresponding expectation:

```
protected Mock<ITicketRepository> MockTicketRepository = new Mock<ITicketRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

UPDATE
I've tried to strip everything back so that the test is as simple as possible to try and isolate the issue. Here's what I have come up with:

```
[TestClass]
public class TicketControllerTests : ControllerTestBase
{
    protected Mock<ITicketRepository> MockTicketRepository;

    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexActionModelIsTypeOfTicketModel()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        MockTicketRepository = new Mock<ITicketRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        MockTicketRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(Constants.TICKET_ID)).Returns(Constants.CLIENT_TICKET);
        var controller = new TicketController(MockTicketRepository.Object);

        //ACT - try to keep ACT as lean as possible, ideally just the method call you're testing
        var result = controller.Index(Constants.TICKET_ID);

        //ASSERT
        var model = ((ViewResult)result).ViewData.Model;
        Assert.That(model, Is.InstanceOfType<TicketModel>(), "ViewModel should have been an instance of TicketModel.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Some of the code I pasted was a result of just toying around with things to get it working. However, using Constants.TICKET_ID has no effect. See the code edit I made a few minutes ago. Even right after I call Setup() in the unit test, I can't get my expected object back so I don't think it's related to the controller. However, the first line (after some guard clauses) is var ticket = _ticketRepository.GetById(id);

Comment: The code in your edit works as expected (no pun intended). If you create a setup on a mock and then check the object property, the actual code that is being mocked hasn't run, so the mocked instance won't contain anything. Remember that moq is used for creating expectations on real objects - it doesn't run in isolation

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I still don't think it's the controller though, like I said, there's nothing fancy going on, just a call to _ticketRepository.GetById(id) where 'id' comes from a route value (and is an integer).

Comment: Could you show the controller constructor where the repository is injected in?

Comment: @Scott, please follow levelnis suggestion to add `MockBehavior.Strict`. If for some reason your setup isn't accessed, the exception message from moq will give information on the parameterization that was not strictly moq'd.

Comment: As suggested, adding MockBehavior.Strict helped to identify where the problem was.